# How to transfer image from button1 to button2?

Tags: android, image, android-studio, button

Is possible to give the background image of a button to another button, like we pass values betweeen variable, in Android Studio?
I want something like:
`btn_1.setBackgroundResource = btn_2.setBackgroundResource`

Comment: yes it is. Get drawable and set drawable.

Comment: Can you tell me how would be the syntax?

Comment: Is this ImageButton or Button?

Comment: It is ImageButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button1.setBackground(button2.getBackground());
```